# Data vs [UInt8]

Tags: swift, nsdata

Swift offers both `Data` and `[UInt8]` types, which do a very similar thing.

- What are the differences between the two?
- When designing new API's, what's the preferred type?

Comment: I'd say that `Data` (~`NSData`) are objects and provide a lot methods that could be useful. But it depends if you need them or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[UInt8]` is essentially a byte array, a byte (as I'm sure you know), is comprised of 8 bits. Whilst NSData isn't simply a byte array, deep down it's underlying structure is based off one. You can easily convert between them using methods such as `data.bytes`, for example.

In terms of designing APIs, I would personally recommend you design them with NSData simply because of all the extra functionality it offers over a simple byte array. Apple has already done a lot of the legwork for you, so why do it again yourself?

Comment: Is `Data` something we are encouraged to use or just to interface with ObjC parts? Do you have popular libraries that use `Data` vs `[UInt8]`?

Comment: What about Linux apps that don't use ObjC parts? Is `Data` popular for those?

Comment: NSData is simply the iOS/OSX way of representing binary data. The data actually exchanged between the app and your backend is usually a base64 encoded string. NSData can easily be converted to this using `data.base64EncodedStringWithEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

Comment: I'm not on iOS, but instead work with some C APIs and other non-iOS Swift APIs. I wonder whether Data is popular outside the iOS/macOS world, or whether it's just used in conjunction with iOS/macOS/ObjC.

Comment: If you are working with C then I would use the byte array. NSData is an apple wrapper around this which extends its functionality. If you're not using iOS/OSX you won't have access to this class anyway.

Comment: The Foundation library is available on Linux as well :-) In the end, I don't think it matters too much. Will try with Data, and revert to [UInt8] when this fails.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach to me! I wasn't aware Foundation was available on Linux. Hey, learn something new every day...

Comment: In your case, if Foundation is available and give some useful methods, you could use `NSData`, but if you do some "simple" stuff, you can keep using `[UInt8]`.

Comment: It's only a light version, but Data is in it – https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation

Comment: Seems like `Data` does not offer everything that `[UInt8]` offers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190415

Comment: It looks like Apple has made a concerted effort to switch from `[UInt8]` to `Data`, at least within the Swift Protobuf project: https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf/issues/129
https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf/pull/134

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using `Data` for most things, but `[UInt8]` has one distinct advantage: you can pass it directly to functions requiring pointers to the bytes like C functions, whereas for `Data` you have to do a bunch more gymnastics. The code below demonstrates the difference for both immutable and mutable arrays and `Data` objects.

```swift
func takesAPointer(_ p: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) {
    // ...
}

let a: [UInt8] = [1, 2, 3]
takesAPointer(a)
let d = Data([1, 2, 3])
d.withUnsafeBytes {
    let p = $0.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self).baseAddress!
    takesAPointer(p)
}

func takesAMutablePointer(_ p: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) {
    // ...
}

var b: [UInt8] = [1, 2, 3]
takesAMutablePointer(&b)
var e = Data([1, 2, 3])
e.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
    let p = $0.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self).baseAddress!
    takesAMutablePointer(p)
}
```