# Passing Data into function that accepts generic collection

Tags: swift, generics, collections

I have a function that accepts generic collections.

```
func foo<T: BidirectionalCollection>(_ bar: T)
    where T.Iterator.Element == UInt8,
          T.SubSequence: BidirectionalCollection & RangeReplaceableCollection,
          T.SubSequence.Iterator.Element == UInt8,
          T.SubSequence.Index == T.Index,
          T.SubSequence.SubSequence == T.SubSequence
{
    //
}
```

I want to call this function with `Data` as T:

```
foo(Data())
```

However, this gives the error:

> error: generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

What's going on here? How to properly call the function with a `Data` instance?

Comment: It works if I pass a `[UInt8]` instead of the `Data`. How is that different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `Data.SubSequence` does not conform to `RangeReplaceableCollection` protocol, while your generic function has this requirement:

```
T.SubSequence: BidirectionalCollection & RangeReplaceableCollection
```

Comment: Wow, and I thought that `Data` was just a glorified `[UInt8]` with more features. Is this a Swift bug or is my understanding of `Data` incorrect?

Comment: @Etan:  `Etan` is a "descendant" of ObjC's `NSData`.  See this for details: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0069-swift-mutability-for-foundation.md.  `NS` prefix was dropped in Swift 3 as a part of bringing foundation classes under standard API guidelines.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov: This is *not* a case of NS prefix dropping (as described in https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0086-drop-foundation-ns.md, eg. `NSBundle` becomes `Bundle`). `Data` is the overlay type of `NSData` and both still exist in Swift.

Comment: What about `Data` in the platform independent Foundation available on Linux? Sorry, I'm a bit confused now.

Comment: @MartinR, yes, my bad.  I had an impression that `NSData` is kept for backward compatibility reasons where reference behavior still needed and going to be dropped at some point later on.

Comment: @Etan, sorry, I do not understand your question.

Comment: Question was meant as `NSData` and the whole objc world doesn't exist there. How can `Data` be a descendant of `NSData` there? @MartinR answer was not displayed for me when I wrote that.

Comment: Foundation, `NSData` included, does exist on Linux. There migh be some bugs, and some functionality not yet fully implemented vs. macOS, but in general it's there. (Sorry for brewity, typing from mobile).