# Why can't Swift Data be freely converted to an UnsafePointer?

Tags: swift

I'm working with a c library that takes in a lot of byte arrays. I can just pass Strings and UInt8 arrays straight in and they'll work as expected. If im using a Data variable though it seems I have to use withUnsafeBytes to get at the memory.

```
let string = "message"
let array = Array(string.utf8)
let bytes = Data(string.utf8)

CALL_C_FUNC(string, Int32(string.count)) //works
CALL_C_FUNC(array, Int32(array.count)) //works
CALL_C_FUNC(bytes, Int32(bytes.count)) //does not work

//instead use:
bytes.withUnsafeBytes { (pBytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
    CALL_C_FUNC(pBytes, Int32(bytes.count))
}
```

When you have functions taking 3 or 4 of these args you end up with unwieldy code.

This answer ([Data vs [UInt8]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873282/data-vs-uint8)) says that Data is generally the preferred way to deal with bytes arrays in Swift. If so, why is it so complex to use them with a c libraries compared to other types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no promise that Data be contiguous (it can be a wrapper around a `dispatch_data` for example). Calling `.withUnsafeBytes` both ensures that the pointer your receive points to contiguous bytes, and that the Data continues to exist for the entire block. If you only have an UnsafePointer, the underlying Data may be released before the pointer goes out of scope (particularly if the pointer is stored or passed anywhere), or may encounter a copy-on-write event that modifies its backing storage.

Comment: Since [the grand redesign](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/20225), `Data` is actually now guaranteed to always have contiguous storage (and conforms to the new `ContiguousBytes` protocol).

Comment: Apologies it's taken me so long to mark this as the answer. This answer was a surprise to me, but explained much about the historical context and design of the class. Definitely not obvious from the documentation. Maybe nicer type casting will follow in the future now it conforms to `ContiguousBytes`.